# How to use multiple push notification services?

Tags: android, push-notification

I have to implement push notification services of Parse and Mixpanel in one project. Parse implemented first, it works. But when I implement Mixpanel, I can't receive push notifications. In what way should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well.. could be your notification ID, just change. 
Dont forget this line:

```
 notificationManager.notify(m, notification);
```

And random notificationid:

```
Random random = new Random();
int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
```